# Performance of pointers in regards to memory cache

Tags: c++, performance, pointers, caching, containers

Consider the following C++ code:

```
struct Data;
std::vector<Data> vData;
std::vector<Data*> vPointers;
```

These two arrays vData and vPointers will be located in two small cache-friendly blocks of memory.

If I ever need to iterate through vPointers, dereference each pointer and access some data members in the original vector, will I incur a cache miss for EVERY iteration of the loop and thus gain a significant loss in performance?

If so, is there an easy way to avoid this?

Comment: This article( http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/780842/Vector-of-Objects-vs-Vector-of-Pointers ) is the first thing that came to my mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance impact of cache misses can be quite significant. for example see Stroustrup's [talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style) that covers list vs vector performance from Going native 2012. How big the effect on your program will be can only determined by measuring.

As for *"How to avoid this?"*:

You could for example have a `std::vector<Data>` and let the small subsystems hold a reference to said vector.

Comment: Wow that was an interesting video alright.
Are there any more in depth studies of list vs vector or at least decent articles about how to maximize efficiency when using vectors?

Comment: There cannot really be "in depth studies" or anything like that on this topic because the performance impact relies heavily on your code, compiler, processor etc. Literally the only way to get information on the performance of your code is measuring. What you can say is that indirection like pointers hurts performance, if this is significant or not is for you to find out.